# What is a "possible state" of a particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, superposition, quantum-states

In an MIT OpenCourseWare quantum mechanics lecture, Prof. Alan Adams claims that given any two possible states of a particle, $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$, the particle can also be in a superposition of $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$. What does he mean by "possible states"? Possible in what sense?

Comment: Well, consider the solutions to the SE for the quantum harmonic oscillator; there are a continuous infinity of solutions.  But almost all of these solutions are not square integrable (normalizable) and, thus, are not physical ('possible') solutions.  Indeed, there are a denumerable infinity of solutions for the QHO that are normalizable which is why the energy levels are discrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He just means possible as in physically realizable.  To understand superposition, you don't need to think more about the specifics of what the particular state is, just that that state is a state the particle could be in.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of a state that wouldn't be possible?

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy For example in the infinite potential well, a state with $\Psi \neq 0 $ outside the well would be impossible, as it would imply infinite energy.  We rule out other states, e.g. discontinuous $\Psi$, or not smooth $\Psi$.

Comment: So a possible state is any state that is a "nice" function (smooth, continuous, normalized, whatever) and that satisfies Schrödinger's equation? If so, then wouldn't it be accurate to say that a state is possible "with respect to" some potential?

Comment: Yes I suppose so, though I guess that's kind of implicit.  But as I say, to understand superposition, you don't need these specifics quite so much, and you can be more precise/accurate later on.  For now you can just as well say $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ are some states you can find the system in.

Comment: One more: So what makes possible states distinct is that they correspond to different initial conditions ($\Psi(x_0, t_0)$)?

Comment: Well yes they should be different, but we don't need to consider time evolution or anything for this.

Comment: @CDCM So, if we have one electron just being stationary (within HUP) in vacuum (or moving straight and no too fast, if this makes it is simpler) with no fields sources around, what specific variables would define its state? And what observables would be affected by these variables being different?

Answer (score 2):

Physics is concerned with the behavior of stuff. The "state" of a system (or particle) is a complete description of its current behavior (e.g. where it is, how fast it's moving, etc.).

Quantum mechanics requires two major leaps in reasoning. First, the traditional descriptors assigned to a system (for instance, position and momentum) no longer specify its state. Now, the state is described exclusively by the wavefunction, and those classical descriptors are "observables" (i.e. measurable quantities) and no longer specifiers of the state.

The second major leap is that a particle's state (read: wavefunction) is no longer mutually exclusive to other states. That means that a particle can be in a **linear superposition** of many equally valid states. That is to say, the particle's state need not be "pure." This is possible because the observables are no longer the specifiers of the states.

When the lecturer says that the particle can be in "many possible states," what he means is that the current wavefunction (read: state) of the particle might be a combination of a large number of "pure" states - each of which is associated with a specific value of a specific observable. When a measurement is made on the system, the particle "chooses" which state it wants to be in and delivers that state's observable's value to the observer.

Comment: I appreciate it, but I don't think you correctly understood my question. You seem to be trying to explain superposition to me.